# Отслеживание версий программы Python

Tags: python, github

у меня есть репозиторий на гит-хабе https://github.com/Vlad9slav/Vladisk, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа следила за актуальной его версией, и если выйдет новая версия - давала пользователю это знать (то есть, писала ему, что вышла новая версия, посмотрите репозиторий). Как это сделать? я в Python новичок)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я исправил пост

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60716016/how-to-get-the-latest-release-version-in-github-only-use-python-requests

Comment: спасибо, если поможет отпишу